# Verify facebook token

Tags: facebook, authentication

I have a client application which authenticates with facebook and returns the token successfully. I would like to persist this data to the server without having to pass the entire object. Instead I would like to pass the resulting token from the client side authentication to my C# api in the authorization header and validate this token on the server.

Question, is it possible to verify the token on the server side? How to do it?

I am doing this via google, and need a facebook equivalent:

```
var googleResult = GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(
                    accessToken,
                    new GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidationSettings
                    {
                        Audience = new[] { "secret key here.apps.googleusercontent.com" }
                    }
                ).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: No, you can not "decrypt" it. But you can verify that it is genuine, via the debug token endpoint.

Comment: Sorry, decrypt may the wrong term. I would like to verify it via the server similarly to how google token is currently being verified.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/%20access-tokens/debugging (yes, Facebook actually managed to put a space at the beginning of a "folder name" there, without the space the URL is currently not working.) How that translates into code with whatever SDK or library you are using, you need to go figure out. A simple `/me` request to fetch basic user details is also an option. If the token is not genuine, that will fail.